# Django: Display image from database in DetailView template

Tags: python, django

I am trying to display all of a user's info on their profile page. This includes their profile picture, however I can't get the image to display. I think everything is right, I've found some stuff on this and I have tried to match it up respectively, however I' clearly missing something. Here is my code:

Model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from users.choices import *

# Create your models here.
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    join_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    user_type = models.IntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES,default=1)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    about = models.TextField(max_length=500,default='about')
    twitter = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    dribbble = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    github = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

UserProfileView:

```
class UserProfileView(DetailView):
    model = UserProfileInfo
```

Profile Template (userprofileinfo_detail.html):

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="sidebar-userinfo">
        <img class="profile-pic" src="{{ userprofileinfo.profile_pic.url }}">
        <h2>{{ userprofileinfo.username }}</h2>
        <p class="accent">Score:</p>
        <p>Score goes here</p>
        <form>
            <button type="submit">Follow</button>
        </form>

        <p class="accent">Title:</p>
        <p class="profile-info">{{ userprofileinfo.title }}</p>

        <p class="accent">Website:</p>
        <p class="profile-info">{{ userprofileinfo.website }}</p>

        <p class="accent">I'm a:</p>
        {% if userprofileinfo.user_type == 1 %}
            <p class="profile-info">Designer</p>
        {% elif userprofileinfo.user_type == 2 %}
            <p class="profile-info">Designer</p>
        {% else %}
            <p class="profile-info">Both</p>
        {% endif %}

        <p class="accent">About Me:</p>
        <p class="profile-info">{{ userprofileinfo.about }}</p>

        <p class="accent">Member Since:</p>
        <p class="profile-info">{{ userprofileinfo.join_date }}</p>

        <p class="accent">Location:</p>
        <p class="profile-info">{{ userprofileinfo.location }}</p>

        <p class="accent">Twitter:</p>
        <p class="profile-info">{{ userprofileinfo.twitter }}</p>

        <p class="accent">Dribbble:</p>
        <p class="profile-info">{{ userprofileinfo.dribbble }}</p>

        <p class="accent">Git Hub:</p>
        <p class="profile-info">{{ userprofileinfo.github }}</p>


    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Have you seen the url in source what it shows using view page source.

Comment: what output you got ?

Comment: This is the URL from the source code `/media/profile_pics/garrett-pro-pic.jpg` which appears to be the right url, the output is just the default "?" thing when it can't find the image

Comment: Is the media url set right in the settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in debug mode, you need to add the following to urls.py at the end:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

To serve the media files while in debug mode

Comment: Got it to work, I had to add it to the project urls and not the app urls. So when I am no longer in debug mode I just remove that and it'll work, or do I have to do something else?

Comment: When you change to production, your static files will be served with Nginx. As long as your Nginx is well setup, it will serve the static and media files using the settings you have made for it.

Comment: Do I have to use Nginx? Can I just install Django on my server, upload my stuff and go?

Comment: No you can't, you will need Nginx and Gunicorn to serve your files. Else you'll be using Apache.